# FTP connection fails when script runs on cron, where working correctly for manual run

Tags: php, ftp, cron

I have wrote a script to connect to FTP, it runs correctly when I do it manually but when I run it as cron, it gives me error while connecting to ftp.
The connection is unsuccessful.

```
    //--------------------------- FTP Credentials --------------------------------------------//
$ftp_server='154.0.174.248';
$ftp_user_name="*******";
$ftp_user_pass="********";
//--------------------------- set up basic connection -------------------------------------//

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die('Connection Unsuccessful');

//------------------------- login with username and password ------------------------------//
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

Comment: have you add the #!/usr/bin/php
at the top of your file?

Comment: no. exactly where should I add it?

Comment: can you provide use the crontab line?

Answer (score 0):

When using crontab to execute a file you should add the type off the file at the very top off your script. In your case you should add `#!/usr/bin/php` at the very top off the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    //code
?>
```

Why you should add it? When the cron is going to execute the file it needs to know what the file type is, and in this method you can declare it.

Comment: please be sure that your php path `whereis php` or `locate php`

Comment: I did what you said, but still it is showing me connection unsuccessful.

Comment: Hmm you havd to check your username and password does the script runs on cron?

Comment: it runs fine when i run it manually, it only gives me problem when i set it as cron

Comment: Paste your cron line on the question

Comment: */2   *   *   *   * php -f /var/www/html/docomo-live/Cron_to_positive_cases.php
 this is my cron tab

Comment: Try to remove the /where the number 2 is

Comment: actually i tried to run that file from teminal, then it also gives me that error

Comment: enable error reporting and run the script. The problem should be on the script